Problems compiling CMSIS-RTOS library in ARM A7 firmware
I'm writing a firmware for STM32MP135 A7 ARM micro.
I'd like to include CMSIS-RTOS2 libraries and compile a simple basic program (to blink 2 LEDS in 2 different threads) by gcc cross toolchain and Eclipse IDE.
To include CMSIS library I downloaded the STM32CubeMP13-main.zip from the ST github site and extracted the folders:

Middlewares/ST/cmsis_rtos_threadx/* (for cmsis_os2.c file)
Middlewares/ST/threadx/common/*
Middlewares/ST/threadx/ports/cortex_a7/gnu/*

The compilation is globally correct; while linking I have 3 problems I'm not able to solve:

undefined reference to `_tx_initialize_low_level' - if I add the file cortex_a7/example_build/tx_initialize_low_level.S I have the error: multiple definition of `__tx_swi_interrupt';
undefined reference to '__get_IPSR'
undefined reference to `SystemCoreClockUpdate'

I'm not able to find these symbols, at least for ARM A7 arch.
-- ADDED
I'm wondering if SystemCoreClockUpdate call is really needed, cause it is present in the main() function and the code was copy-and-pasted from a source originally developed for other ST micro.
